# C++ Class Object destructor control

Tags: c++, class, object

Can i control when the object destructor

```
    Class::~Class(){
    cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
    };
```

is called? or It will always be called after the work with a Object.
anyway can someone explain how the destructor works properly and how to manage it.

Comment: Well pick any C++ manual and from object allocation on stack/heap to destructors it'll guide you to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call destructor by calling `delete` on created object (eg. on object created viz new). For structs, destructors are called, when objects is no longer in active function, so after you call return, all structures are "deleted" by OS

Basicly, every new in your code, should have `delete` when you are no longer need your object (or before you close your app). Same goes for `malloc`, should be released with `free`. Dont mix arrays and objects. `new[]` must end with `delete[]`, not with `delete`.